# How can I control the error bar colors to be the same as geom_point colors?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, errorbar

I wanted to make a point plot in ggplot and I used `geom_point` function to do it. To colorize the points, I used levels to fill them either in red or blue. However, now I'm adding the error bars to my point plot with `geom_errorbar` function, it seems I can't give the colors I used in geom_points. In other words, I can only give them one color, which is by default black. Is there any way I can control the color of the error bars?

Let's say we have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame (Xvalue=c(1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.4, 2.7),
                 Yvalue=c(12, 15, 17, 24, 27),
                 Kind=c('A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
                 Ymax=c(13, 16, 19, 26, 29),
                 Ymin=c(11, 14, 15, 22, 25))
df$Kind = factor(df$Kind)
```

Now I want to draw the plot with the error bars:

```
myplot <- ggplot (df, aes(Xvalue, Yvalue, fill=Kind)) + 
  geom_point( shape=21, size= 4, alpha= 0.7)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Ymin, ymax=Ymax,  width=0.08))
myplot
```

[image]
This results in a plot with error bars of black. How can I make sure this is the same color as the points?

Bonus question: Is this how you would usually make two colors in your points, I mean by putting the "levels" in the ggplot function as fill? Do you have an alternative way to where one doesn't need to use Shape=21, where the outer pirameter of the circle is black?

Bonus qeustion 2: Is it generally easier to plot two kinds of points, when they are in 1 dataframe, or is it better to seperate the dataframes? For instance, I can have a smaller dataframe for the Kind A, and another one for dataframe B. Would that make the life easier? Why I'm asking is that, when I tried to plot with more than one levels (for instance once "Kind" and the other one "Original country"), it was quite confusing to plot points in different colors and sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `color` `aes` to your `geom_errorbar` like this (Please note: you could add `show.legend` FALSE to your `geom_errorbar` so there is no line in your elements of your legend):

```r
library(ggplot2)
myplot <- ggplot (df, aes(Xvalue, Yvalue, fill=Kind)) + 
  geom_point( shape=21, size= 4, alpha= 0.7)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Ymin, ymax=Ymax, width=0.08, color = Kind), show.legend = FALSE)
myplot
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If you want the error bar behind your point, just swap the commands in order.

Comment: Wow thanks, that was very fast. Can I also customize it? For instance make it give it the following values: pointcolors = c("#f70000", "#1e28e6").

Comment: Hi @Reza, Yes sure! You could add: `scale_color_manual(values = c("#f70000", "#1e28e6"))`

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't fully get it. Adding this term that you wrote to ggplot didn't change the color. To be clear:  I want to change the color of the points AND the error bars at the same time.

Comment: @Reza, You have specified the `fill` to your points so if you want to have it in one call you should also change that to `color` or use also `scale_fill_manual` like this: `myplot <- ggplot (df, aes(Xvalue, Yvalue, fill=Kind)) + 
  geom_point( shape=21, size= 4, alpha= 0.7) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Ymin, ymax=Ymax, width=0.08, color = Kind), show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#f70000", "#1e28e6")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#f70000", "#1e28e6"))`